# Return Json from Values Controller Instead of String

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the Values controller in Net Core VS 2019 to send JSON data back instead of string. This is the syntax I am using that is not accurate:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult({
            "heroesUrl": "api/heroes",
            "textfile": "assets/textfile.txt"
        });
    }
}
```

I get red squiggly lines indicating a syntax error on the JSON objecs in the {}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anonymous object instead.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
    return new JsonResult( new {
        heroesUrl = "api/heroes",
        textfile = "assets/textfile.txt"
    });
}
```